# Check that png image and csv file has the same name before processing them

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas, png

l have a dataset (5000 data) composed of images and csv files. Each image is mapped with its csv files. for instance `img_33e_78.png` is mapped with`img_33e_78.csv`.
For each image l have a csv file which contains a given pixels to process.
To do so l need to check that l'm processing the image with the right csv file . This is why l need to check the name of image and csv. the difference is only on `.png` and `.csv`.
here is my code :

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import h5py


indir_images="image"
os.chdir(indir_images)
images_name=glob.glob("*.png")


indir_csv="clean_data"
os.chdir(indir_csv)
csv_names=glob.glob("*.csv")

for img,csv in zip(images_name,csv_names):
    if (image_name == csv_name) #here l need to ckeck that the image and csv file have the same name
        # do the processing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose i would start with making sets of your images and csv files. i remove the file extensions because they are the real issue of comparing the files.
This is done using a list comprehension. could also be done using map.

```
image_names = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in glob.glob('*.png')])
csv_names = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in glob.glob('*.csv')])
# Alternatively using map
image_names = set(map(lambda x: x.rsplit('.', 1)[0], glob.glob('*.png'))
```

Then we make a superset with ones where we know we have both.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

```
for name in image_names & csv_names:
    open(name+'.jpg)
    etc...
```

that way you know you have all files that match.

Comment: @Ajuma, but how can  l access for example to the second file with your solution image_names[2] and csv_names[2] returns 
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: for name in image_names & csv_names:   does't wor l tried to print("hello") inside it doesn't print anythning even with for name in zip(image_names,csv_names)

Comment: using the for loop we are iterating through all the names that match. since they match we can open them by adding the file extension,
image_names & csv_names creates a new set which contains members that exist in both sets.